# Error in sudo apt-get update

Tags: 18.04

```
volition@sjb:~/gd/openslide-3.4.1$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntukylin.com:10006/ubuntukylin xenial InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                          
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                            
Hit:5 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                            
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hzwhuang/ss-qt5/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Hit:7 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease  
Hit:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:9 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                  
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hzwhuang/ss-qt5/ubuntu bionic Release         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/hzwhuang/ss-qt5/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 1):

The PPA `ppa:hzwhuang/ss-qt5` isn't update since 06-08-2017 and has no release file for Bionic. That's the reason why you are getting such errors. It is recommended to remove this PPA using:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:hzwhuang/ss-qt5
```

or purge it using:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:hzwhuang/ss-qt5
```

And try updating again.